# JAXB 2.x: Abstract methods get marshalled as Attribute

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, abstract-methods, moxy

I have an abstract root class, let's say `A`.

And I have several implementation classes extending `A`.

`A` has FIELD annotation as well as some `@XmlElement` annotated properties.

`A` also has an abstract method.

When marshalling (`B extends A`), the value returned by the abstract method gets marshalled as attribute. Not as expected, right?

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class SpecialProfile extends ContentNodeBean {

  @XmlElement(name="do-index", namespace="my")
  private boolean doIndex = false;

  public abstract SpecialProfileType getSpecialProfileType();

  ... getters and setters for properties ...   
}
```

Does anybody have the same issue and how can this be fixed?

I am using org.eclipse.persistence.moxy 2.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am attempting to reproduce your issue, but so far have been unsuccessful.  Can you see where I'm doing something different than you are?  The following is my sample code:

**A**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class A {

    public abstract C getC();
    public abstract void setC(C c);

}
```

**B**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class B extends A {

    private C c;

    @Override
    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

}
```

**C**

```
public class C {

}
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import org.eclipse.persistence.Version;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Version.getVersionString());

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(B.class);
        System.out.println(jc);

        B b = new B();
        b.setC(new C());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(b,System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
2.1.2.v20101206-r8635
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext@100ab23
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b"><c/></b>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments:

- B does not inherit A's XmlAccessorType settings.
- It is not the abstract method that you need to mark @XmlTransient, but the field used to implement the accessor on the B class.

The following is what class B should look like:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B extends A {

    @XmlTransient
    private C c;

    @Override
    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, looking at your Output, the <c/> gets marshalled although c should not get marshalled, right? There is no field annotation. What I am expecting is that C does NOT get marshalled...

Comment: Also: is B inheriting the @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) annotation from A? I have set that annotation in B too, just to be sure.

Comment: and also: I have tried the @XmlTransient annotation on the abstract methods in class A, it is still marshalling it.

Comment: Ok, this I understand, but in my case there is no property c that I could annotate. The object is created on the fly. Is this maybe the problem?

Comment: Created on the fly, as in using ASM to generate the class programatically?